# Gitkraken Desktop App - Error login: "Please log in to continue"

Tags: git, github, sourcetree, gitkraken

Who has been working with client GitKraken as GIT, you will know that authentication required?

For the application, log in with: **firstemail@outlook.com**

The repository is with: **businessemail@bussiness.com**

It requires credentials to make a pull, but I tried with both emails and usernames, and does not allow me.

Capture:
[image]

In ***SourceTree*** it works perfectly, but here not!.
Thanked fully!.

Comment: Check if you have any network capture tools running or proxies setup. For instance Fiddler with HTTPS decrypting can cause this behavior.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The credentials asked for, are the credentials for the repo you are trying to access, not for your Gitkraken account, which is very confusing.

If you are using visualstudio.com, you would have to generate Git credentials. Do this by browsing to your project, click '**Code**' and then on the right top corner, there is a button '**clone**'. Press that, a popup opens. In there, click '**generate git credentials**'. Fill in a username/password combo and press '**save git credentials**'. That combo will now work with GitKraken.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the exact same problem, the solution for me was simple. Just had to reconnect my GitHub account inside GitKraken settings and after that everything came back to normal.
For this, go to (GitKraken -> Preferences -> Integrations -> GitHub -> Connect GitHub account)

Comment: This is the way

Comment: Somehow, the authentication link when using `Connect to GitHub/Bitbucket` gets quickly rerouted to the Error 1007 page.  I cant find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding additional information, as this just bit me today.

The login credentials it is requesting are from visualstudio.com (VSTS).  Authenticating to VSTS through GitKraken request a personal access token (PAT) or git credentials (as mentioned by user Roet).  Personal access tokens can be created through the VSTS web portal, as described in this blog post (no relation):
[Personal Access Tokens in VSTS](http://blog.devmatter.com/personal-access-tokens-vsts/)

Answer (score 2):

I think gitkraken have a bug.
On version 1.9.3 they specified that

> Oh dear. Our 1.9.2 update broke fetching, pushing and pulling when connecting to hosts without GitKraken integration (GitLab, etc). This should now be working as expected

I'm on 1.9.3, but I still have the problem
Check your version and be patient :)

Comment: same problem here. i have tried my gitlab credentials with no success. And i'm using 2.6 version

Answer (score 0):

see the log files of Gitkraken. It can't access some files on the filesystem ? => run it as administrator => it worked for me

Comment: Where are the log files for gitkraken located?

Comment: Logs are at `Help < Support Logs`

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue after a system crash.  After getting back into the system, I try to push to the repo and Gitkraken asks me for the credential.  I go to `Preferences` -> `Integrations` -> `Bitbucket.org` -> `Connect to Bitbucket`.  It then opens a link like this:

```
https://api.gitkraken.com/oauth/bitbucket/login?action=authorize&socket_id=XXXX&in_app=true
```

That page quickly reroutes to `https://www.gitkraken.com/error?error=1007` with the message `Oh no! An error occurred.`:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElkB.png)

This happens very quickly, so it is really challenging to capture that `api.gitkraken.com` link.  It doesn't matter how many times I retry clicking on that `Connect Bitbucket account`, it still sends me to the same page.  Finally, I quit Gitkraken and repeat the process.  This time it works.  Hope this will help whoever finds this post.

This works with Virtualbox 6.* and Ubuntu 20.04 but fails with Virtualbox 7.* and Ubuntu 20.04.  Any insight is appreciated.